# Identify Elements with Particular Class Prefix

Tags: javascript, html, css, class, dom

I have a `div` and a `span` as it's child element.

```
<div class='template_field dynamic_font'>
    <span>Im a text!</span>
</div>
```

I have to change span's text to something. Below is what I did:

```
var myid_info_registrar = document.querySelector(".template_field > span");   
myid_info_registrar.innerHTML = 'Dynamic';
```

It throws an error, because I supplied the querySelector with .template_field only. What will I do to change the span's text given only the prefix class of the parent div, which is `template_field`.

Comment: Your given code should be perfectly fine, and should not throw an error if your js code runs at the time where the elements exits in DOM: [jsfiddle - demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7sb8cu7q/) . Most likely you call you js code in the head of your document.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ztjkp4uk/1/ - just fine - make sure your script is executed after the elements are created